# Nokia 6212 platformRequest() to open a video

Tags: java-me, mobile, nokia

How can the platformRequest method defined in [MIDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Information_Device_Profile) 2.1 [JSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) be used to open a video on a [Nokia 6212 Classic](http://www.mobile88.com/cellphone/Nokia/Nokia-6212-Classic/preview.asp)?

The Forum Nokia Library states:

> In Series 40, native applications are
>   launched with platformRequest(localapp
>   method. The following opens the Photos
>   folder in Gallery.
>
> platformRequest("localapp://gallery/show?folder=C:/predefgallery/predefphotos");

Currently I have tried the following (and more):

I did make sure the resource as availble at the location given as the folder argument.

```
platformRequest("localapp://gallery/show?folder=C:/Gallery/Video Clips/Material.mp4");
platformRequest("localapp://gallery/show?folder=C:/gallery/video clips/material.mp4");
platformRequest("localapp://gallery/show?folder=C:/Material.mp4");
...
```

For testing purposes to open an image I tried,

```
platformRequest("localapp://gallery/show?folder=C:/Gallery/Images/Image001.jpg"); //Gallery.

platformRequest("localapp://gallery/show?folder=C:/predefgallery/predefphotos") //Failed as well :-(
...
```

All fail with the following error message.

> ConnectionNotFoundException: Invalid URL.

It is obivious what the problem is but I cannot determine the correct way to tell the phone where a file is and what to open it with using the URL.

(I have asked the question on the Nokia Forum but to no avail. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your application signed for the Manufacturer or Operator domain? Quote from the [Forum Nokia Library](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-09E205E4-72D8-49A3-AF80-CA15804C9163.html):

> Start local application. In Series 40,
>   only allowed for manufacturer and
>   operator MIDlets. In Symbian Java all
>   domains work but only some
>   applications are supported.

The 6212 is a Series 40 device. Although I wouldn't expect a ConnectionNotFoundException (rather a SecurityException), this won't work unless you have you midlet Manufacturer/Operator signed.

Comment: its been tesed in signed and unsigned

Comment: Signed specifically for the Manufacturer or Operator domain?